# Taylor & MacLaurin series

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have a problem that I can not understand at all.
I know how to calculate taylor/macLaurin for $\cos x$, $\sin x$ and  $e^x$ etc.
However when I have for example:
$\sin x \cos x$  or $\sin x + \cos x$ or $\sin x-\cos x$ I have no idea how am I supposed to calculate this.
Could you give me some hints on  how to do such thing?

Comment: Write down the series for $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, then multiply them out, add them term-by-term, or subtract them term-by-term as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in this type of functions, then it is useful to convert the functions as linear combinations of the functions $e^{iax}$ and then find the the $n$th derivative which you need to construct Taylor series. If you are interested in more general techniques, see [section 6](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4FXAHVyGS9KZWIzZjIxZGQtN2M4NC00N2MzLTk1YmQtM2M2NmVhYmE4NzA5/edit?hl=en_US).